# Java hmac algorithm not working properly

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(
        "CnZ3QvfIjYLL0FWDQeY9L+1XLQKv0jtufAqUcXYP9krzAjhYJvOuiAdBZqt9Ogw7".getBytes(),
        "HmacSha1");

Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSha1");
mac.init(keySpec);
byte[] result = mac.doFinal("pesho".getBytes());

String decoded = new String(result);
System.out.println(decoded);
BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
System.out.println(encoder.encode(result));
```

which outputs:

```
ё|zЅ!)fЮпFгЅ$‰ж<Т.
Grh8Dnq9ISlm3u9G470kieY80i4=
```

when it should be outputting:

```
1ab87c0e7abd212966deef46e3bd2489e63cd22e
MWFiODdjMGU3YWJkMjEyOTY2ZGVlZjQ2ZTNiZDI0ODllNjNjZDIyZQ==
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works correctly. It just returns the `byte[]` array and you convert it to `String`, but what you really need is to get the hex representation of this byte array. You can convert byte array to hex string using the `bytesToHex` method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855338/4856258):

```
SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(
        "CnZ3QvfIjYLL0FWDQeY9L+1XLQKv0jtufAqUcXYP9krzAjhYJvOuiAdBZqt9Ogw7".getBytes(),
        "HmacSha1");

Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSha1");
mac.init(keySpec);
byte[] result = mac.doFinal("pesho".getBytes());

String decoded = bytesToHex(result).toLowerCase();
System.out.println(decoded);
BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
System.out.println(encoder.encode(decoded.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)));
```

This produces exactly what you want.